# XSLT rewrite nested xml elements as one element with a comma seperated value string

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I want to transform this all property elements as comma seperated string as one element in xml with xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
<Product>
<productId>1</productId>
<ean>12345</ean>
<title>title A</title>
<Properties>
<Property><key>Colour</key><value>Red</value></Property>
<Property><key>Material</key><value>Plastic</value></Property>
</Properties>
</Product>
<Product>
<productId>2</productId>
<ean>54321</ean>
<title>title B</title>
<Properties>
<Property><key>Colour</key><value>Black</value></Property>
<Property><key>Gender</key><value>Boys</value></Property>
<Property><key>Material</key><value>Leather</value></Property>
</Properties>
</Product>
</Products>
```

Required output using XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
<Product>
<productId>1</productId>
<ean>12345</ean>
<title>title A</title>
<Properties><Property>Colour:Red,Material:Plastic</Property></Properties></Product>
<Product>
<productId>2</productId>
<ean>54321</ean>
<title>title B</title>
<Properties><Property>Colour:Black,Gender:Boys,Material:Leather</Property></Properties>
</Product>
</Products>
```

The result xml as to be flattened without nested structure. If anyone has a better idea to get the propertytypes as elementnames then it would even be better.

If it is possible to get:

```
<Properties><Colour>Black</Colour><Gender>Boys</Gender><Material>Leather</Material></Properties>
```

I hope to hear from you!

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. Also please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Do note that using strings as element names is possible only if the original strings will always be valid XML element names.

Comment: I am not familiar with xslt, so I do not know how to do this and I cannot find it somewhere on the net. So yes, I am asking to give me a xslt in the right direction to accomplish this.

Comment: Spend an hour with an XSLT tutorial and you will know how.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <ean>12345</ean>
        <title>title A</title>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <key>Colour</key>
                <value>Red</value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <key>Material</key>
                <value>Plastic</value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <productId>2</productId>
        <ean>54321</ean>
        <title>title B</title>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <key>Colour</key>
                <value>Black</value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <key>Gender</key>
                <value>Boys</value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <key>Material</key>
                <value>Leather</value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property">
        <xsl:element name="{key}">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <productId>1</productId>
    <ean>12345</ean>
    <title>title A</title>
    <Properties>
      <Colour>Red</Colour>
      <Material>Plastic</Material>
    </Properties>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <productId>2</productId>
    <ean>54321</ean>
    <title>title B</title>
    <Properties>
      <Colour>Black</Colour>
      <Gender>Boys</Gender>
      <Material>Leather</Material>
    </Properties>
  </Product>
</Products>
```